# haarcascade mouth smile xml for EmguCV old version

Tags: c#, xml, computer-vision, emgucv, detection

I'm using quite an old version of EmguCV which dll-s is a 2.2.1.1150

This XML-s works fine with new versions of library

1. [haarcascade_smile.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_smile.xml)
2. [haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml)
3. [haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/data/cascades/haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml)

but none of this XML-s versions work with 2.2.1.1150 version of EmguCV library, throws an exception:

> The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)

I'm trying to find some .xml for mouth smile detection compatible with EmguCV version 2, also I'm not sure if I am able to do this without CascadeClassifier.

2.2.1.1150 successfully uses such xml-s as haarcascade_frontalface_default dated 2000. Аapparently I should find a similar haarcascade of mouth smile about 2000, but it seems quite old, maybe impossible

Comment: The XML structure has changed in the last file.  The one that is not working looks like it has a date of 2006 while the working ones have 2008.

Comment: @jdweng Hello, sorry my question not was clear, now edited

Comment: It looks like the version of EmguCV is not backwards compatible with last XML file which is 2006.

Comment: @jdweng Yes exactly, and seems like there is no suitable xml version for particular library version, or i just can't find it